# Desplegando React en Heroku: TypeError: t.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, http, axios, heroku, cors

Mi aplicación react funciona perfecto pero una vez desplegada en heroku veo esto en la consola y la data no se muestra, estoy obteniendo la data usando axios haciendo get a un endpoint online, estoy usando configuraciones de proxy en el package.json para eludir problemas de CORS:

```
TypeError: t.map is not a function
    at j (Nav.js:9)
    at ro (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Bo (react-dom.production.min.js:180)
    at Wi (react-dom.production.min.js:269)
    at Pu (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at Cu (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at xu (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at vu (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)
```

Mi componente Nav.js -> es donde la consola indica que esta el error

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

const Nav = ({ planetas }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <section className="middlenav">
        <div className="list-container">
          {planetas.map((planeta) => {
            return (
              <div className="a-container" key={planeta.codigo}>
                <a href={planeta.nombre}>/:{planeta.nombre}</a>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

mi componente App.js -> Hace la petición GET y la envía via props a los hijos

```
import "./App.css";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Header from "./Header";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Gallery from "./Gallery";

const App = () => {
  console.log("APP LOADED!");
  const [planetas, setPlanetas] = useState([]);
  const getPlanetas = () => {
    axios.get("/test/ta/sistema_solar.json").then((response) => {
      setPlanetas(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getPlanetas();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="maindiv">
      <Header />
      <Nav planetas={planetas} />
      <Gallery planetas={planetas} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```